# ANOVA in python

Tags: python, scipy, static-analysis, statsmodels

My csv file contains discrete and continuous variables and I would like to find the "equation of model" which explains my continuous variable (a) according to my discrete variables(x,y,z);
->a=f(x,y,z).The problem is that i'm trying this code but it fails. When I want to see the result of the print([f_value, p_value] stats.f_oneway = (x, y, z)), I get [nan, nan]. Extract from my code:

```
from numpy import (genfromtxt,hstack,arange)
#Pr linear regression
from scipy import stats
import scipy
#Pr ANOVA
from statsmodels.stats.multicomp import (pairwise_tukeyhsd,MultiComparison)

from pylab import savefig
from matplotlib.pyplot import (figure,setp)

fname="G:/table.csv"
my_data = genfromtxt(fname,delimiter=',')

#Transformation of file into table

x= my_data[:,3]
y= my_data[:,4]
z= my_data[:,6]


#one way anova
[f_value, p_value] = stats.f_oneway(x, y, z)
```

I want estimate the model R=u+f(x,y,z)+ e where R (continuous variable), u  (constant), e (measurement error). I want have the coefficients for how the discrete variables affect my continuous outcome.

Comment: if anyone knows another way, please help me because I'm searching in internet but I'm finding statsmodels librarie and scipy which is used for ANOVA but I dont know how to do and how to apply these libraries.

Answer (score 3):

My best guess is that your data contains NaN values, or bad values. You could try to detect is with following piece of code:

```
for i in range(1,len(x)):
    (f_val,p_val) = stats.f_oneway(x[:i],y[:i],z[:i])
    if numpy.isnan(f_val) or numpy.isnan(p_val):
        print i-1,x[i-1],y[i-1],z[i-1],f_val,p_val
```

Comment: Sorry to insist, but this is working: stats.f_oneway([1,2,3],[1,4,6],[2,1,3]) will return (1.000000000000002, 0.42187499999999944) whereas stats.f_oneway([1,2,3],[1,4,6],[2,1,numpy.NaN]) will return (nan,nan). Could you please show the result of this command: "print x[:3],y[:3],z[:3],stats.f_oneway(x[:3],y[:3],z[:3])" ?

Comment: Yes you are right, but i dont understand why when I make stats.f_oneway (x, y, z), will return (nan, nan)and (x,y,z) are an array like this: array ([5, 5, 5, ..., 2, 7, 7......]),array...
The result of the print command x [:3],y [:3],z [:3], stats.f_oneway (x [:3],y [:3],z [:3]),will return [ 5.  5.  5.] [ 31.  31.  52.] [ 1.  1.  1.] (25.244897959183675, 0.0011982397810415284)

Comment: ok, can you give us the result of "print numpy.NaN in x,numpy.NaN in y,numpy.NaN in z"

Comment: i dont inderstand, you want to print the result of numpy.NaN.x?
what is the syntax because i'm debutante in python.

Comment: this syntax just check if some NaN values exists in the arrays, you just need to copy/paste the command

Comment: "in" IS the command, really, simply copy/paste this in your command prompt: "print numpy.NaN in x,numpy.NaN in y,numpy.NaN in z"

Comment: No, `in` doesn't work for nan checking with numpy arrays, use `numpy.isnan(x).any()`

Comment: numpy.isnan(x).any(),will return True.

Comment: I want estimate the model R=u+f(x,y,z)+ e where R (continuous variable), u (constante), e(erreur de mesure).I want the coefficients for how the discrete variables affect my continuous outcome.

Comment: There would be different ways to "solve" this, the question is : why is it happening and what do you want to do? So you need to investigate your data, and 1) understand why some values are missing (the piece of code I added in my answer should help to show where it happens); And 2) depending on this first question, either reject NaN measures, or replace them by a fixing value